# How to display data in columns that contains values when filtered by name

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have employee data in a worksheet. I would like to be able to filter out employee column by name and it will only display the data that is not blank while retaining column titles. For instance if I select name 4, it will only give me values for locality 1 and 3 with headers.

This is what the table looks like:

[image: Employee Table]

Comment: Would a Pivot Table work?

Comment: It's quite natural,, if you select `Name4` then Excel will return only the related values from `Loc1 & Loc3`,, what else you are expecting !!

Comment: Thank you for responses, there are 100s of localities in the actual spreadsheet. my problem is if you filter out by name it leaves blanks present. I would like to select a name and it will only give me localities that have values in them. So if name 4 is selected and only locality 1 and Locality 2 will appear with values associated with them. I tried to use Pivot table and it does not ignore blanks for some reason but I may not be doing it right. Thanks again

Comment: Do you want to get the result like this?  https://ibb.co/NSBv2Yn  If yes, I will provide the steps.

Comment: Yes that may work, I really appreciate it